# Immutability and thread-safety in Scala

Tags: java, scala, thread-safety, immutability

I'm reading the book [Java concurrency in practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) and when I read about the relation between *immutability* and *thread-safety* I tried to get deeper. So, I discovered that there is at least a use case in which the construction of an immutable class in  Java can lead to the publishing of a non properly constructed object.

According to [this](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#finalRight) link, if the fields of the class are not declated `final`, the compiler could reorder the statements that needs to be done in order to construct the object. In fact, according to [this](https://assylias.wordpress.com/2013/02/01/java-memory-model-and-reordering/) link, to build an object the JVM needs to do these non-atomic operations:

1. allocate some memory
2. create the new object
3. initialise its fields with their default value (false for boolean, 0 for other primitives, null for objects)
4. run the constructor, which includes running parent constructors too
5. assign the reference to the newly constructed object

My question is: what about Scala? I know that Scala is based on the concurrency model of Java, so it is based on the same Java Memory Model. For example, are `case class`es thread-safe wrt the above construction problem?

Thanks to all.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713665/must-access-to-scala-collection-immutable-list-and-vector-be-synchronized

Comment: Post that as an answer maybe?

Comment: @SteveWaldman, could you summurize the answer that are give to the question you've gave? I tried to read them, but there is too much information, and the focus is not exactly the same of my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There's no answer accepted. One poster made a long argument for the claim that Scala's core immutables are thread-safe as long as you are access them from outside of `scala._` packages, but I did not find that answer ultimately persuasive. I think Thread safety issues may be unlikely in practice unlikely with e.g. List and Vector, but I think the Java memory model is sufficiently flexible that safety cannot be guaranteed if you don't synchronize access. I find that extremely disappointing, but so far, no one has made a persuasive-to-me case for a guarantee of safety. Do see @axel22's comments.

Comment: Excuse me @DanielL., what do you mean?

Comment: @riccardo.cardin the same you said on your first comment.

Comment: Ah ok, now I have undestood. Sorry :P

Comment: @SteveWaldman I think I found an answer to my question :)

Comment: @DanielL. I think I found an answer to my question :)

Comment: @riccardo.cardin great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some deep  search on Stackoverflow and on the Internet. There is not so much information about the question I've made. I found this question on SO that has an interesting answer: [Scala final vs val for concurrency visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626611/scala-final-vs-val-for-concurrency-visibility).

As proposed by @retronym I've used `javap -p A.class` to destructure a `.class` file containing a `case class` and compiled by `scalac`. I found that the class

```
case class A(val a: Any)
```

is compiled by the scala compiler into a corresponding Java class that declares its unique attribute `a` as `final`.

```
Compiled from "A.scala"
public class A implements scala.Product,scala.Serializable {
  // Final attribute
  private final java.lang.Object a;
  public static <A extends java/lang/Object> scala.Function1<java.lang.Object, A
> andThen(scala.Function1<A, A>);
  public static <A extends java/lang/Object> scala.Function1<A, A> compose(scala
.Function1<A, java.lang.Object>);
  public java.lang.Object a();
  public A copy(java.lang.Object);
  public java.lang.Object copy$default$1();
  public java.lang.String productPrefix();
  public int productArity();
  public java.lang.Object productElement(int);
  public scala.collection.Iterator<java.lang.Object> productIterator();
  public boolean canEqual(java.lang.Object);
  public int hashCode();
  public java.lang.String toString();
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
  public A(java.lang.Object);
}
```

As we know, a `case class` in Scala generates automatically a bunch of utilities for us. But also a simple class like this

```
class A1(val a: Any)
```

is translated into a Java class that has a `final` attribute.

Summarizing, I think we can say that a Scala class that has only `val` attributes is translated into a corresponding Java class that has `final` attributes only. Due to the JMM of the JVM, this Scala class should be *thread-safe* during the construction process.